# SetTimeOut while drawing multiple images into canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, settimeout, draw

Basically, I'm drawing several pieces of an image in a canvas. Some pseudocode:

```
for(i=0; i<16; i++)
{
piece = arrayWithImagePieces[i];
 setTimeOut(canvas.draw(piece), 3000))
 }
```

This should draw the pieces in a canvas like an animation. But it doesn't happen. why?

Comment: Welcome to SO! `setTimeOut` and `canvas.draw` aren't functions, but even if they were, `setTimeout` accepts a callback and `canvas.draw()` probably doesn't return a function--you don't want to invoke it immediately. Please post a [mcve] using actual code that shows the problem not working and I'm sure we can set you on the correct path. Chances are, you need something like `setTimeout(() => { /* now make your draw calls */ }, 3000)`. Thanks!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Fj64HAac === What the loop does is that it draws multiple pieces  of image of equal size inside a square canvas (until the image is whole inside the canvas). What I want to do is make some kind of animation using setTimeOut. Basically, after each individual 'piece' is drawn, I want to make a pause, then draw next one. The code as it is now draws all the pieces concomitantly.

Comment: @SpamSpasmodium could you please create a working example of what you are attempting; like on https://jsfiddle.net or https://jsbin.com

Comment: Or better yet, put it in the question itself. Links can go down over time.